# Solr dynamic sorting

Tags: solr, solr4

We have a website on which you can search through a large amount of products from different shops. Say we have 5 products per result page and the 10 best matches for a search have all the same score. 8 of the products are of one shop (A), and the two others by two other shops (B,C).

What we often get is (letter indicating a product of this shop)

1. A
2. A
3. A
4. A
5. A

---- second result page ----

1. A
2. B
3. A
4. C
5. A

but what we want to get is something like this:

1. A
2. C
3. B
4. A
5. A

---- second result page ----

1. A
2. A
3. A
4. A
5. A

Writing function query seems to be one option
http://www.solrtutorial.com/custom-solr-functionquery.html

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the criteria of sort in your mind? Can you put that in an expression?

Comment: The sort logic needs to know the count(resultshopitems) to do uniform distribution of results. Is there way to get the count(resultshopitems) using expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the results by shop using [Field Collapsing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) and display the result either as a group or flattened list (depending on how you want it).

Another trick that I've seen in use to help the users see results from multiple group is to use Facets. You could have a sidebar (or something similar) that does two things:

1. By default it lets the user know that there are other filter criteria (ex. shops) in the result. This helps a lot when the result is paginated.
2. With facets being present, it is upto the user to choose whatever criteria she/he wishes to apply, thus relieving you of implementing heavy scenario based logic.

Read more about faceting [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview).

Edit:

If you have to use custom sort logic, you could write it down using Functions and use it in the sort when querying Solr. [Here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function) is the reference from the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, these possible options I considered. But we prefer to have custom sorting logic. Anythoughts on cutom function query to implement this?

Comment: Yes, if you want custom logic, then building a function and passing it as the `sort` parameter works. Have updated my answer

Comment: But I want to have custom logic in sorting which cant be achieved by function query available methods.

Comment: That's what I asked earlier - if you can have your sort logic as an expression (math formula) then you can check if function query is an option. Otherwise, it is difficult to give an answer without understanding how exactly you are aiming to sort the results.